# Computer Architecture Execute Cycle Substruction with Registers

Tags: cpu-architecture, execution, cpu-registers, instructions, microprocessors

There is a problem with a question:

If "ADD R1, X" that procces explain in execution cycle like that:

```
t1: MAR <- (IR(address))
t2: MBR <- Memory
t3: R1  <- (R1) + (MBR)
```

How can we write about "SUB R1, R2" and "MUL R1, R2"

MAR: Memory Adress Register
MBR: Memory Buffer Register

Also I have seen MDR. Are MDR and MBR same thing?

Comment: What does [tag:atomicity] have to do with this?  What other observer within the system is potentially observing this?  DMA?  Another CPU core?  For instructions between two registers, the effects aren't even visible outside the CPU core.

Comment: We learned this at univercity under "atomicity at program execution" topic. Sorry about that. I do not know much. I asked about it to assistance of prof. she did not say anything about that question. She wanted me to find it myself.